# getter attribute on property does not match inherited from NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have recently updated to xCode 6.1 and ever since then I'm getting this warning msg for on my project Which was running smoothly without errors and warnings

getter attribute on property does not match inherited from NSOperation

Below is my code

```
@interface HttpTransceiver : NSOperation {

@private
    ServiceRequest     *m_serviceRequest;
    BOOL                m_executing;
    BOOL                m_finished;
    NSURLConnection     *m_urlConnection;
    NSInteger           m_statusCode;
    NSMutableURLRequest *m_urlRequest;
    NSMutableData       *m_receivedData;
    NSHTTPURLResponse   *m_receivedResponse;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)    ServiceRequest *serviceRequest;
@property                       BOOL            executing;
@property                       BOOL            finished;
```

***@property                       BOOL                        executing;***
This is the line where I'm getting above warning. I tried to adjust property but it didn't workout.
Please Advise

Thanks

Comment: use `@property (readonly, getter=isExecuting) BOOL executing;`

Comment: Thanks Anoop Actually m_executing did work well.. I tried it before as well but it was still giving me warning. But when I cleaned project with all the warnings gone.. thanks

Comment: @MayurCM: so maybe remove question or answer yourself?