# New "property does not match the property inherited from UIViewController" error after upgrading to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xcode8

Just upgraded from Xcode 7 to 8, and am now getting the following error on a property in my header file:
`getter attribute on property does not match the property 'beingDismissed' inherited from UIViewController`

What changed in this version of Xcode that would cause this error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124219/getter-attribute-on-property-does-not-match-inherited-from-nsoperation

Comment: It's obvious -- the definition of the property changed.  As you haven't bothered to even tell us which property is causing you trouble, there's nothing more to add.

Comment: Updated the question with the property name. But what I'm also curious about is why this error wasn't shown in Xcode 7

Answer (score 0):

It happened because UIViewController don't have a `beingDismissed` property. It's just have a method

`- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);` So you can use it like

```
if ([viewController isBeingDismissed]) {
    //some stuff
}
```

Description for this method

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the view controller is
>   in the process of being dismissed by one of its ancestors.

Comment: It looks like it is a property? `@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isBeingDismissed) BOOL beingDismissed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);`

Comment: It can be a private property in @interface extension. Not in header file